# Building GCC 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to install GCC 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04, but during make I get the error shown below where compilation aborts. (To the best of my knowledge I have all prerequisites satisfied as I have already gcc 4.7.2 compiled, installed and running on my system. I manage different versions of gcc using package manager 'stow'.)

Does anybody have a solution or a clue to a solution, please?

```
$ ./configure --prefix /usr/local/stow/gcc-4.8.0
...
$ make
[ -f stage_final ] || echo stage3 > stage_final
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0/host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
if [ x"-fpic" != x ] && [ ! -d pic ]; then \
      mkdir pic; \
    else true; fi
touch stamp-picdir
CONFIG_FILES= CONFIG_HEADERS=config.h:../.././libiberty/config.in /bin/bash ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default commands
if [ x"-fpic" != x ]; then \
      gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  -fpic ../.././libiberty/regex.c -o pic/regex.o; \
    else true; fi
In file included from ../.././libiberty/regex.c:52:0:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:99:17: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:110:19: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
../.././libiberty/regex.c:132:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:132:7: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:133:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:133:7: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘realloc’ [enabled by default]
In file included from ../.././libiberty/regex.c:640:0:
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘byte_regex_compile’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:2441:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:2441:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:2502:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:2535:36: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:2642:28: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:3645:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:4152:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘byte_re_compile_fastmap’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:4837:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘abort’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../.././libiberty/regex.c:4837:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘byte_re_match_2_internal’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:7426:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘xregcomp’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:7980:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘xregexec’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:8055:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘xregerror’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:8083:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
../.././libiberty/regex.c: In function ‘xregfree’:
../.././libiberty/regex.c:8116:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
make[3]: *** [regex.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0/host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-libiberty] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

UPDATE:

I found the following error log in build-dir/host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/config.log

```
$ more ./host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/config.log 
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/me/Downloads/gcc-4.8.0/libiberty/configure --cache-file=./config.cache --prefix /usr/local/stow/gcc-4.8.0/ --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc --program-tr
ansform-name=s,y,y, --disable-option-checking --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=i686-pc-linux-gnu --srcdir=../.././libiberty --disable-intermodule --enable-c
hecking=yes,types --disable-coverage --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ubuntu
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.5.0-26-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 11 22:19:42 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2223: creating cache ./config.cache
configure:2374: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2384: result: no
configure:2399: checking for makeinfo
configure:2426: result: makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --split-size=5000000
configure:2466: checking for perl
configure:2482: found /usr/bin/perl
configure:2493: result: perl
configure:2512: checking build system type
configure:2526: result: i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2546: checking host system type
configure:2559: result: i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2584: checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-ar
configure:2611: result: ar
configure:2676: checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib
configure:2703: result: ranlib
configure:2796: checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:2823: result: gcc
configure:3092: checking for C compiler version
configure:3101: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3112: $? = 0
configure:3101: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/stow/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/gcc-4.7.2/
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC) 
configure:3112: $? = 0
configure:3101: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3112: $? = 1
configure:3101: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3112: $? = 1
configure:3128: gcc -o conftest -g  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3131: $? = 0
configure:3160: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3182: gcc -g  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3186: $? = 0
configure:3223: result: a.out
configure:3239: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3248: ./a.out
configure:3252: $? = 0
configure:3267: result: yes
configure:3274: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3276: result: no
configure:3279: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3286: gcc -o conftest -g  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3290: $? = 0
configure:3312: result: 
configure:3319: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3341: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3345: $? = 0
configure:3366: result: o
configure:3370: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3389: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3389: $? = 0
configure:3398: result: yes
configure:3407: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3427: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3427: $? = 0
configure:3468: result: yes
configure:3485: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3549: gcc  -c -g  conftest.c >&5
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:389:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from conftest.c:10:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
... 
[The logfile continues with several other errors similar to this.]
```

Comment: Can some moderator move this question to stackoverflow, please? I think this is a non-trivial problem but gets too low attention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for records, I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 x84_64 and everything worked perfectly. Just installing the dependencies and no errors occurred. Nevertheless, I don't know why it didn't work with Ubuntu 12.04 i386.